# Upload a file to a specified directory using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify my php script to allow me to upload iamges and files to a specific folders within my program. At the moment I have a couple of php files that return a string of all the files held on my server and a script that only uploads images to the root of the server.

For example my get directory script will return something like this:

> Img1.jpg
>
> Img2.jpg
>
> Folder.folder

I've got it so I can click and store what ever has been clicked on in this string and I want to pass it to my php script so that I can I upload my next image to folder.folder as opposed to the root.

How can I go about doing that?

My php code for upload the file is as follows:

```
<?
    $uploaddir = './';
    $file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    print_r($_FILES);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://ipAddress/serverFolder/{$file}";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "Failed to upload file";
      }
?>
```

Is there a best practise for going about doing what I wish to do?

I'm really new to PHP so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change $uploaddir = './'; to $uploaddir = './Folder.folder/';

Answer (score 0):

Store the current directory in a session variable and then use that in your uploading script.

When a link is clicked:

```
$_SESSION['directory'] = $_POST['directory'];
```

And then in your uploading script:

```
$uploaddir = './'.$_SESSION['directory'];
```

After which you **must** perform some kind of validation to make sure that the directory being uploaded to is somewhere you actually want the files to be uploaded to. After that you can continue with the upload.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are using form to upload a file and you want to specify a directory.
Simply add `<input type="text" id="folder" name="folder">` where you can write directory path and then you can write it in in `$uploaddir = $_POST['folder'];` variable, assuming you are using post.